# Fancybox - Scrolling / page position

Tags: scroll, fancybox, scrollto

I am trying to automatically scroll to a anchor when opening a fancybox iframe like so: www.example.com/posts#header.

It kinda works but it scrolls to the wrong position, either too far up or way too far down (mostly way too far down).

I tried using the jQuery ScrollTo plugin but it also scrolls to the wrong position and additionally "pops out" the page from the fancybox to the whole window.

Would be thankful for any tips on how to get this working!